# Using jQuery UI: How do I add an image to the dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popupwindow

I am using jQuery UI and I want to add an icon within the dialog box.
The dialog works fine, but I'd like to add a picture to be more attractive. I will appreciate any help.

**Code:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal message</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />!-->

<script>
$(function() {
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
modal: true,
buttons: {
Ok: function() {
$( this ).dialog( "close" );
}
}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog-message" title="Download complete">
<p>
<!--<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 50px 0;"></span>!-->
<span style ="float: left; margin:0 7px 50px 0; width:50px; height:37px;"><img src = "img1.jpg"></span>
Your files have downloaded successfully into the My Downloads folder.
</p>
<p>
Currently using <b>36% of your storage space</b>.
</p>
</div>
<p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put an `<img>` tag inside the `dialog-message` DIV.

Comment: @ Barmar  that what i did but the icon or the picture do not show

Comment: You need to brush up on your basic HTML, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about putting anything in a dialog; it's just an ordinary HTML DIV.

The problem is that you're not using correct HTML for your image. Change this line:

```
<span img src = "img1.jpg" style ="float: left; margin:0 7px 50px 0; width:50px; height:50px;"></span>
```

to:

```
<span style ="float: left; margin:0 7px 50px 0; width:50px; height:50px;"><img src = "img1.jpg"></span>
```

`img` is not an attribute of a `<span>`, it's an element of its own.

Answer (score 0):

All that jQueryUI's dialog() does is (1) hide the specified div upon document.ready, then (2) display it with some fancy css formatting when the `.dialog('open')` method (or just the dialog({ //options go here }) method) is called.

Therefore, if your div contains the image WITHOUT the jQUI dialog being instantiated, then it will contain the image AFTER the jQUI dialog method is used.

Your problem is likely the syntax error where you are missing the closing angle bracket for the `<span>` element, and the opening angle bracket for the `<img>` element. Also, the attributes that you desire for the `<span>` element seem to be attached to the input element.

Removing your in-line CSS (for simplicity), this will work:

```
<span><img src = "img1.jpg"></span>
```

Comment: i edit my question and change the line of the span and img  but still not having the icon to be displayed

Comment: Does your image actually exist, and does it exist in the folder you specify (just the document root)?  If you add a new image tag to the top of your document, just as a test, does the image display there?